# undefined method `halt_callback_chains_on_return_false=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm upgrading a Rails 5.1 application to 5.2. I've updated all of my gems including Rails and finally ran `rails app:update` which created new files for my rails app.

Specifically there are two files that were created that concern me. First in `config/initializers` there is a `new_framework_defaults_5_2.rb` file and second (in the same directory) a `new_framework_defaults.rb`. The first file only contains comments, but the second file contains some new configuration options. One of those options is this:

```
ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
```

This method call throws a undefined_method error. What do I need to do with this line of code?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    73: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    72: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    71: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    70: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    69: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    68: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    67: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    66: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    65: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    64: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    63: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    62: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
    61: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
    60: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    59: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    58: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
    57: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
    56: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    55: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:51:in `start'
    54: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:89:in `log_to_stdout'
    53: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:354:in `wrapped_app'
    52: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:27:in `app'
    51: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:219:in `app'
    50: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/server.rb:319:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    49: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    48: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
    47: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
    46: from config.ru:in `<main>'
    45: from config.ru:in `new'
    44: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
    43: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
    42: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    41: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
    40: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
    39: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
    38: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
    37: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
    36: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    35: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
    34: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    33: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
    32: from /home/www-upload/treadmilldoctorcurrent/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    31: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:361:in `initialize!'
    30: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    29: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    28: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    27: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    26: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    25: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    24: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    23: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    22: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
    21: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
    20: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
    19: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    18: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    17: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    16: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    15: from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/lib/ruby/2.5.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    14: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    13: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    12: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    11: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `block in <class:Engine>'
    10: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:613:in `each'
     9: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:614:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
     8: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:656:in `load_config_initializer'
     7: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:170:in `instrument'
     6: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:657:in `block in load_config_initializer'
     5: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
     4: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
     3: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
     2: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
     1: from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/home/www-upload/treadmilldoctorcurrent/config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined method `halt_callback_chains_on_return_false=' for 
ActiveSupport:Module (NoMethodError)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoMethodError: undefined method \`halt\_callback\_chains\_on\_return\_false=' for ActiveSupport:Module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744200/nomethoderror-undefined-method-halt-callback-chains-on-return-false-for-acti)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I encountered the same issue during my last upgrade from 5.1 to 5.2.
What I did is just comment out this line in `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb`

```
# Do not halt callback chains when a callback returns false. Previous versions had true.
# ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false
```

I guess the reason it raise this error because `halt_callback_chains_on_return_false` option is actually remove from ActiveSupport according to [this release note](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_2_release_notes.html#active-support).

Answer (score 5):

This is the previous behavior:

```
WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action: -> { return false }

  def index
    # would not be called
  end
end
```

What the `halt_callback_chains_on_return_false = false` does:

```
WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action: -> { return false }

  def index
    # would now be rendered regardless of the before_action filter chain's return value
  end
end
```

What Rails thinks you should do in filter chains to prevent rendering:

```
WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  before_action: -> { raise 'Error' }

  def index
    # would not be rendered
  end
end
```

Hope this helps.

Best,
Emil

Answer (score 2):

```
  halt_callback_chains_on_return_false setting in the initializer
```

This was a solution for temporary keeping old callback behaviour after upgrade to Rails 5.0. Assumed that you need time to check all callbacks in the app and after it you can remove this setting. And assumed that on the upgrade to 5.2 all is already checked, so this setting is removed.

Just comment out the line as @worrawut recommends in the
        config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb file.

Comment: isn't there a good way to check callbacks automatically?