# How does rails understand that the past version of the application and shield against current updated changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

The post is just to understand how rails understand the past version of my application and shield it against current breaking changes.

We recently upgrade our app from 4.2+ -> 5.0. One of the changes that Rails implemented in Rails 5 is the use of `throw(:abort)` in `before_*` callbacks to break the chain (if there ever need be) and the use of `false` would simply have no side effect (i.e no callback chain will be halted when used `false`) (Please take a note of this)

But here a catch. If you read [this](https://gist.github.com/claudiob/614c59409fb7d11f2931) this states clearly that if you are upgrading from `4.2 -> 5.0` the `return false` inside `before_*` callbacks would still work.(with a warning but will work)

So here my question after the update when I have the Rails, AR and AS gem to 5.0.0.1 version locked on my Gemfile.lock, how does Rails knows that I have upgraded the app from 4.2 and it has to respect the `return false` statement in the before_* callback which it would not if you create a fresh  application in Rails 5.0

Possible a link to source code will also be helpful.

Comment: Please, check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49744200/nomethoderror-undefined-method-halt-callback-chains-on-return-false-for-acti/49745260#49745260) This info is stored in initializer

Comment: @Vasilisa Thanks @Vasilisa But I believe I found the reason how it understands the if the app is 4.2 or 5.0  so my understanding is the ActiveSupport.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false (default value is true) can be seen over [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17227/files#diff-1ecd313ff0ab827af30014553cf8918dR523) but since the Rails-5 has a new_framework_defaults.rb initializer which set the value to `false` and Rails-4 does not it understand allow the `return false` in the before_* callbacks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer (Quick way to ensure upgrade compatibility):

- Read and follow the [official "upgrading" page](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html)
- Specifically in your case, it's [Upgrading Rails 4.2 to 5.0](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-4-2-to-rails-5-0)

### Answer (Detailed way to understand what has changed):

1. Go to the release notes. i.e. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html
2. Go to the [Deprecations](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations) section, or if you have already are aware of some change, then find it on that page (i.e. find the text `"throw(:abort)"`)
3. Click the ["Pull Request" link](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17227) there
4. Then click the the ["Files Changed" tab](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/17227/files)
5. Then read all of the `CHANGELOG.md` files; I quote (and to answer your question):

   > Setting `Callbacks::CallbackChain.halt_and_display_warning_on_return_false`
   >   to true will let an app support the deprecated way of halting callback
   >   chains by returning `false`.
   >
   > Setting the value to false will tell the app to ignore any `false` value
   >   returned by callbacks, and only halt the chain upon `throw(:abort)`.
   >
   > The value can also be set with the Rails configuration option
   >   `config.active_support.halt_callback_chains_on_return_false`.
   >
   > **When the configuration option is missing, its value is `true`, so older apps
   >   ported to Rails 5.0 will not break (but display a deprecation warning).
   >   For new Rails 5.0 apps, its value is set to `false` in an initializer, so
   >   these apps will support the new behavior by default**

**Regarding your concern about breaking changes, it's good to keep in mind that:**

Rails seems to use a **different** version of "Semantic Versioning":

I quote from @rafaelfranca [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9979#issuecomment-44596397):

> X.Y.Z
>
> Z - only bug fixes, no API changes.
>
> Y - new features, may contains API changes.
>
> X - new features, will contains API changes. Just bumped in special occasions

And I quote @robin850 [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9979#issuecomment-76940306)

> when the Y is incremented there may be features that are deprecated but they are still available but when it's incremented again, these features may not be there anymore (e.g. `Numeric#ago` was available in 4.0, deprecated in 4.1 and removed in 4.2).

Personally, I developed my gems using standard "semantic versioning", so that

- any X change means non-backwards-compatible change, and that my dependent projects/code probably wouldn't work anymore
- while any Y change is a backwards-compatible "feature" change
- while any Z change is usually just minor bug fixes.

That's why if you do a `rails new some_project`, and then checked the `Gemfile`, you'll see `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'`. Because if Rails was "semantically-versioned", it would instead look like `gem 'rails', '~> 5.2'`